# Problems where element is not added when adding elements in the recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

There was a problem with the recyclerview list being added only initially and not being added after the second.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.added_data.Companion.start_time_hou
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.added_data.Companion.start_time_min
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.model.UserData
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.view.UserAdapter

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var addsBtn:FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var recv:RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userList:ArrayList<UserData>
    private lateinit var userAdapter:UserAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        userList = ArrayList()
        addsBtn = findViewById(R.id.addingBtn)
        recv = findViewById(R.id.mRecycler)
        userAdapter = UserAdapter(this,userList)
        recv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recv.adapter = userAdapter
        addsBtn.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,next_activity::class.java))
        }
        if(intent.hasExtra("name")){

            addInfo2()
        }

    }
    private fun addInfo2(): ArrayList<UserData> {
        var names = start_time_hou
        var number = start_time_min
        userList.add(UserData("Name: ${names}","Mobile No. : $number")) 
        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() 
        Toast.makeText(this,"${userList}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        return userList
    }
}
```

UserAdapter.kt

```
package com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.view

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.R
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.model.UserData

class UserAdapter(val c:Context,val userList:ArrayList<UserData>):RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>()
{

  inner class UserViewHolder(val v:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
      var name:TextView
      var mbNum:TextView
      var mMenus:ImageView
      var mToggle:ToggleButton

      init {
          name = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mTitle)
          mbNum = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mSubTitle)
          mToggle=v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton)
          mMenus = v.findViewById(R.id.mMenus)
      }
  }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
       val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        return UserViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {

       val newList = userList[position]
        holder.name.text = newList.userName
        holder.mbNum.text = newList.userMb
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return  userList.size
    }
}
```

next_activity.kt

```
package com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.added_data.Companion.end_time_hou
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.added_data.Companion.end_time_min
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.added_data.Companion.start_time_hou
import com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.added_data.Companion.start_time_min
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_next2.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.add_item.*

class next_activity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
        button.setOnClickListener {
            start_time_hou="1"
            start_time_min="2"
            end_time_hou=3
            end_time_min=4
            val intent_time= Intent(this@next_activity,MainActivity::class.java)
            intent_time.putExtra("name","lir")
            startActivity(intent_time)
        }
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            start_time_hou="1123"
            start_time_min="52"
            val intent_time= Intent(this@next_activity,MainActivity::class.java)
            intent_time.putExtra("name","lir")
            startActivity(intent_time)
        }
    }
}
```

added_data.kt

```
package com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview

class added_data {
    companion object {
        var start_time_hou = "0"
        var start_time_min = "0"
        var end_time_hou = 0
        var end_time_min = 0
    }
}
```

UserData.kt

```
package com.malkinfo.editingrecyclerview.model

data class UserData (
    var userName:String,
    var userMb:String
        )
```

What I want is to move from MainACtivity to next_activity, and every time I press the button in next_activity, a new recycleview element is created. However, as I said earlier, there is no additional generation and only one element of data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, you are adding items to your `userList` in `MainActivity` but you are not passing them to the `recyclerview`. That is why `userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is not causing any effect.

Try this and let me know if there is still some issue :)

> In MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var addsBtn:FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var recv:RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userList:ArrayList<UserData>
    private lateinit var userAdapter:UserAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        userList = ArrayList()
        addsBtn = findViewById(R.id.addingBtn)
        recv = findViewById(R.id.mRecycler)
        userAdapter = UserAdapter(this)
        userAdapter.setData(userList)
        recv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recv.adapter = userAdapter
        addsBtn.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,next_activity::class.java))
        }
        if(intent.hasExtra("name")){

            addInfo2()
        }

    }
    private fun addInfo2(): ArrayList<UserData> {
        var names = start_time_hou
        var number = start_time_min
        userList.add(UserData("Name: ${names}","Mobile No. : $number")) 
        userAdapter.setData(userList)
        Toast.makeText(this,"${userList}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        return userList
    }
}
```

> UserAdapter

```
class UserAdapter(val c:Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>()
{

 private var _userList: ArrayList<UserData>? = null

  inner class UserViewHolder(val v:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
   var name:TextView
   var mbNum:TextView
   var mMenus:ImageView
   var mToggle:ToggleButton

  init {
      name = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mTitle)
      mbNum = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mSubTitle)
      mToggle=v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton)
      mMenus = v.findViewById(R.id.mMenus)
   }
 }

fun setData(userList: ArrayList<UserData>) {
    _userList = userList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
UserViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
    return UserViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {

   val newList = _userList?.get(position)
    holder.name.text = newList?.userName
    holder.mbNum.text = newList?.userMb
}

 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    if(_userList == null) 
      return 0
    else 
      return _userList!!.size  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There was a problem with the "_userList" part of the recommended method, so I tried changing it to "private lateinit var _userList: ArrayList<UserData>".There was no error, but there was a problem that the app was forced to close when running.

Comment: can you explain a bit about `There was a problem with the "_userList" part of the recommended method`?

Comment: Error " only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type kotlin.collections.ArrayList<UserData>?/8=java.util.ArrayList<UserData>?*/" occurred in "return  _userList.size" and "val newList = _userList[position]".

Comment: So I tried changing "private var _userList: ArrayList<UserData>? = null" to "private lateinit var _userList: ArrayList<UserData>" as the first attempt. No error occurred, but there was a problem that the app was forced to close when running.

Comment: In the second attempt, I changed "val newList = _userList[position]" to "val newList = _userList?.get(position)" and changed "return  _userList.size" to "return  _userList!!.size", and then tried to run it, but this also caused a problem that it was forced to quit.

Comment: try now and let me know :)

Comment: Thank you. No errors, no forced shutdown. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: great! is your issue completely resolved now? If yes, then mark it as an accepted answer so others know this question doesn't need any more help now :)